# How to use RowReaderFactory in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm trying to have a key value pairRDD from a cassandra table.
And I encountered a Class that seems really nice at first glance : **RowReaderFactory**

```
RowReaderFactory<Dog> dogRRF = new RowReaderDogFactory();
RowReaderFactory<Owner> ownerRRF = new RowReaderOwnerFactory();
JavaPairRDD<Owner, Dog> indexPairRDD = functions.cassandraTable(keyspace, "dog", ownerRRF, dogRRF);
```

With my RowReaderFactory defined like this (same for the Owner)

```
public class RowReaderDogFactory implements RowReaderFactory<Dog> {

    @Override
    public RowReader<Dog> rowReader(TableDef arg0, RowReaderOptions arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public RowReaderOptions rowReader$default$2() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Dog> targetClass() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

I don't get how I'm supposed to use this RowReaderFactory class.

I obviously get a nullPointer when running this... And I didn't find any explaination with example on the internet.

Any help would be appreciated !

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example shown in this link [Spark RowReaderFactory](https://github.com/boneill42/spark-on-cassandra-quickstart) should help you. I haven't looked in detail to write what i understood. However, boneill42 (Sorry, If i misspelled the name. I could find this as a username of the author.) has provided the complete working example which helps in debugging.

I referred this when i was looking for some Spark SQL stuff from [Spark SQL](http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/spark-sql-against-cassandra-example/). Which is also informative just for reference.